# Azure graph api is not working for previous page request (&previous-page=true)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using azure AD and importing users and groups from azure. It is working fine with next page request.

I am using microsoft test azure ad from below.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/blob/master/GraphConsoleAppV3/Constants.cs

But not working with previous page. the query I am using as follows,

```
"https://graph.windows.net/schoolneo.net/users?api-version=1.6&$top=200&$filter=accountEnabled eq true&$skiptoken=X'445370.....0'&previous-page=true"
```

It is showing `"The remote server returned an error(400). Bad request"`. I have checked with api-version 1.5 also. Not working.

**Note:** I am sure that it was working long back. Now only it is not working. Wondering if this support have changed.

Please share your concerns. !!!

Comment: When testing, I run into the error: `"code":"Request_UnsupportedQuery","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Invalid previous page search request."` Do you get the same error or a different one?

Comment: Get same error("Invalid previous page search request.") as shown by @ShawnTabrizi . That seems currently it doesn't support `previous-page=true` with the filter query.

Comment: I am getting bad request error only @Shawn

Answer (score 1):

I got `400 Bad Request` error and inner message is `Invalid previous page search request` as shown by @ShawnTabrizi . That shows currently Azure AD Graph API doesn't support `previous-page=true` with the `filter` query . If you remove the filter query part , the previous page search request will work .

If you want Azure AD Graph API supports previous page search with the filter query , you could send a  feedback in [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c?query=assignments) .

Comment: I will use search query to get the users from azure ad. So I must use filter query. It will work if we remove filter. But I couldn't.

Comment: @DAon , you may send your feedback and request for official support.